# RegisterClientScriptBlock & RegisterClientScriptInclude do not work in Composite C1 when integrated in user control

Tags: user-controls, c1-cms

I try to add custom javascript block from within user control in Composite C1. The user control is integrated in a nested master page (called Frontpage.master - as basis starter site "ASP.NET Master Pages" from Composite C1 has been taken and I want to stick with it as close as possible).

For analysing the problem very simple code has been used within user control:

```
    string _jsScriptBlock = "alert('here');";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ClientScriptManager scriptMgr = this.Page.ClientScript;
            if (!scriptMgr.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(this.GetType(), "jsScriptBlock"))
            {
                scriptMgr.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "jsScriptBlock", _jsScriptBlock, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

The same code works in another test ASP.NET website integrating user control within nested master page. RegisterClientScriptInclude is not shown here, but it's exactly the same problem.

As a workaround I could add Javascript block and script link directly in markup of user control and master page, but I prefer "dynamic" solution by registering if necessary.

Does anybody know, if this problem is a general issue with Composite C1 framework?

Comment: what is the actual behavior when running your code? do you get any errors, or what happens?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clearer. The code does get executed without any exceptions, but finally it does not seem to have any effect - neither Javascript block nor script link are available. Thanks!